# All zero values passed in the table

Tags: php, mysql

When I execute this code, I only get zeroes inserted into my database. Why? What can I do to solve this problem?

```
<select class="date" name="year"> <option value="">Year</option>
<?php $i=1; while($i<=31) { ?>
<option value="<?php $i ?>"> <? echo $i; ?> </option>
<?php $i++; } ?> </select>
```

And this is my mysql code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO information ( Year ) 
VALUES ('$_POST[year]')";
```

Comment: nothing is right , both the code and the sql are wrong

Comment: what data type is the column "Year" in your database table?

Comment: You're showing a query to insert the (uncleaned) year, but your HTML is for the day. Wha?

Comment: That's a mistake, I fixed it now. @Josh

Comment: Please don't name your table "information".  That is about as undescriptive a name as could possibly exist, along with "data".  All tables contain information and data.  What is in the table?  What does that year represent?  Think of the next programmer who has to maintain your code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LZwDMEsW please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here how it will be your code

```
     <select class="date" name="year">
       <option value="">Year</option>
         <?php  for($i=1;$i<=31 ;$i++ ) { ?>
       <option value="<?php $i ?>"> <? echo $i; ?> </option>
         <?php } ?>
     </select>
```

EDIT :

```
    <input type ="submit" value =" submit me"/>
    <?php  if (isset($_POST['year']))  // check if isset the year
       {
       $year = $_POST['year']  ;
       } else {}



    $sql="INSERT INTO information ( Year ) VALUES ('".$year."')";
       ?>
```

edit 2 :
your code is right but you should escape value to prevent sql injection 
do like that

```
insert into ....
    VALUES
       ('mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[user])','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[email])'.........
```

Comment: Just judging by the OPScode, the `$i<=31` Represents the day. There is a maximum of `31 days in a month` Not the year

Comment: That's not the real problem Daryl. It's just an example.

Comment: @user1902462  if u mean the month , just replace the year by the month

Comment: @user1902462 i think u still miss some code to submit and code to define the POST . and then insert to mysql

Comment: @user1902462 this the whole code to submit and define post year and then insert it to mysql

Comment: Yes, all time I got zero till now :(

Comment: as i told u make submit button , hidden fields if it needs , define post variables and then insert them to mysql

Comment: yes your code is right but missing to work , just do what i told u and it will work . ur html is right , ur sql right but just escape variables to prevent from sl injection .and then do what u are missing

Comment: something doesn't quite look right here: `<?php $i ?>` with no echo? and `mysql_real_escape_string()` php function in quotes as part of the SQL statement?

Comment: `<?php $i ?>` it will be read ,better with `<?php echo $i ; ?>`.and  `mysql_real_escape_string()` yes i have tried it and it works , and he can also make `$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);` and then use $var in his sql . if he uses `'$var'`  mean that he can also use `'mysql_real_escape_string($var)'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select class="date" name="day"> <option value="">Day</option>
<?php $i=1; while($i<=31) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php echo $i; ?> </option>
<?php $i++; } ?> </select>
```

Always use `<?php` and `?>` so your browser recognizes PHP

also, with your first `<?php $i ?>`

I changed this to `echo $i;`  and on the same line I changed `<? echo $i; ?> </option>` To `<?php echo $i; ?> </option>`

and it worked for me.

With Your Insert:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO information (COL_FOR_DAY) 
VALUES ('{$_POST['day']}')";
```

Comment: so your **browser** can parse php? :P